# Angular2 - webpack - Separate modules into more production files

Tags: angular, webpack, dev-to-production

I have a few modules for a regular web visitors. Then, much more modules are used for the app back-office that doesn't have to be loaded with the public site.

What is the right way to create two production bundle files with different modules? I use webpack.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to create *chunks* of js files.

You'd need to set-up the modules for Lazy Loading, and then configure `CanLoad` guards for each of the routing branches - Back-office and Public.

That way, there is only one bundle, but only the JS relevant for that particular route is loaded.

You can read a great explanation by Victor Savkin [here](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb#.khhnkfgzc).

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, I found a few useful resources that can help for this topic.

Additionally to jsfrocha's answer.  That approach is good for SPA pages. Each module is loaded on demand.

https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb#.otgochysw
https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee#.qorg2knor

For multipage application, we need a separate file for each page, plus a common file for all of them. This topic is discussed here:

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application

A tutorial for webpack setting:  http://tektutorialshub.com/angular-2-with-webpack-tutorial/